# Change AD Computer Description via CSV and Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, csv, wmi, wmic

I'm fairly new to scripting in PowerShell, therefore, please pardon my skill...

I have this mini project to update AD computers descriptions based on the following format from a CSV file I have: 
last user logged in, full name of that user, IP address of the machine, Computer manufacturer and model, serial number

jdrit | Joe Dirt | 10.10.10.10 | Dell OptiPlex 380 | 123456

... I searched the internet, but seems that everything needs to be done via WMCI object call. I was able to complie some code

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer 
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
$vendor = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).Vendor
$name = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).Name
$identifyingNumber = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).IdentifyingNumber
$vendor
$name
$identifyingNumber
Set-ADComputer $computer –Description “$vendor | $name | $identifyingNumber”
}
```

Would someone help a brother out? or point me in the right direction.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Nice that you posted some code. Where is it going wrong? What error message? Please [edit] the question and update. Do not reply in the comments.

Comment: There is no error. I just need help completing the script. For example, how do I tell the script to look at a CSV file for the computer name I'm trying to update the description for? I also need help ID the WMI object to get the IP, last user and user full name.